# Why won't router.delete, delete item from mongoose db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When trying out the route on postman, it returns the id, but has not been removed from my database.

Here's my delete request, any thoughts?

```
router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Job.findByIdAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, job) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.json({ msg: "job deleted", deleted: job });
    } else {
      console.log("Error in employee delete :" + err);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
Job.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (err, job) => { /* ... */ })
```

The [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndDelete) says:

> `findByIdAndDelete(id)` is a shorthand for `findOneAndDelete({ _id: id })`

Comment: same issue, just returns id and doesn't delete from db

Comment: Also make sure to sanitize your input `req.params.id` maybe you want to `trim` it

Comment: I believe it's my route, when changed to `router.delete('/' ...` i get the json response but job is null obviously.